# On EC2: node.js without sudo

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I cannot run 'node myApp.js' on my EC2 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server.

It replies with error:

```
events.js:66
throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:768:11)
    at HTTPServer.Server._listen2 (net.js:891:19)
    at listen (net.js:935:10)
    at HTTPServer.Server.listen (net.js:984:5)
```

I've googled around, but no solution that seems to fit.

Comment: Are you listening on port number 1024 or below?  Those require sudo.  Ports above that should work w/o sudo.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux only root is allowed to use ports<=1024. If you want your web server to listen on port 80, let your app listen on a port>1024 (i.e. 8080) and use iptables to reroute to that port like so:

```
# sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```